# Missing name for redirect error

Tags: port, forward

I'm on FreeNAS and installed OpenVPN in a jail. I want to portforward a port to my jail using OpenVPN. I followed this [guide](https://gist.github.com/caseyWebb/f869c3d9afab064e94b1dc9f021b89d8/4b05e93c63684ea1a95518fcfbd8a6a04461b1d5#file-port_forward-sh) to portforward using OpenVPN, but it doesn't work.

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Enable port forwarding
#
# Requirements:
#   your Private Internet Access user and password as arguments
#
# Usage:
#  ./port_forward.sh <user> <password>

error( )
{
  echo "$@" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

error_and_usage( )
{
  echo "$@" 1>&2
  usage_and_exit 1
}

usage( )
{
  echo "Usage: `dirname $0`/$PROGRAM <user> <password>"
}

usage_and_exit( )
{
  usage
  exit $1
}

version( )
{
  echo "$PROGRAM version $VERSION"
}

port_forward_assignment( )
{
  echo 'Loading port forward assignment information..'
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]; then
    if type ip >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
      local_ip=`ip addr show tun0 |  grep "inet " | head -n 1 | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d\  -f2 | tee /tmp/vpn_ip`
    elif ifconfig tun0 | grep -oE "inet addr: "; then
      local_ip=`ifconfig tun0 | grep -oE "inet addr: *10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | tr -d "a-z :" | tee /tmp/vpn_ip`
    else
      local_ip=`ifconfig tun0 | grep "inet " | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d\  -f2 | tee /tmp/vpn_ip`
    fi
  fi
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    local_ip=`ifconfig tun0 | grep "inet " | cut -d\  -f2|tee /tmp/vpn_ip`
  fi
  client_id=`cat /tmp/vpn_client_id`
  json=`wget -q --post-data="user=$USER&pass=$PASSWORD&client_id=$client_id&local_ip=$local_ip" -O - 'https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/vpninfo/port_forward_assignment' | head -1`
  echo $json
}

EXITCODE=0
PROGRAM=`basename $0`
VERSION=1.0
USER=$1
PASSWORD=$2

while test $# -lt 2
do
  case $1 in
  --usage | --help | -h )
    usage_and_exit 0
    ;;
  --version | -v )
    version
exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    error_and_usage "Unrecognized option: $1"
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if [ ! -f /tmp/vpn_client_id ]; then
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]; then
    echo head -n 100 /dev/urandom | md5sum | tr -d " -" >> /tmp/vpn_client_id
  fi
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    echo head -n 100 /dev/urandom | md5 -r | tr -d " -" >> /tmp/vpn_client_id
  fi
fi

port_forward_assignment

exit 0
```

At first I got a "Command not found" error, but that was because of a space in the shebang line. Then, I edited the script, and now I get a different error "Missing name for redirect".

```
root@transmission_1:/usr/local/etc/openvpn # ./port-forward.sh <myusername> <mypassword>                                                                        
Missing name for redirect.                                                      
root@transmission_1:/usr/local/etc/openvpn # bash port-forward.sh <myusername> <mypassword>                                                                     
Missing name for redirect.                                                      
root@transmission_1:/usr/local/etc/openvpn #
```

I've read that this may be caused because I'm not using bash. However, I tried executing the script with the command "bash" at the beginning of the line, so I figure I should be ok, but it still output the same error. As a note, I login in the jail using the "jexec tranmission_1 tcsh" command. I also tried to login in the jail in a bash shell, but then I got other errors (either syntax eroor or bad interpreter).

```
[root@freenas ~]# jexec transmission_1 bash                                     
[root@transmission_1 /]# cd /usr/local/etc/openvpn                              
[root@transmission_1 /usr/local/etc/openvpn]# ./port_forward.sh <myusername> <mypassword>                                                                       
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'                                    
[root@transmission_1 /usr/local/etc/openvpn]# bash port_forward.sh <myusername> <mypassword>                                                                    
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'                                    
[root@transmission_1 /usr/local/etc/openvpn]# ./port_forward.sh myusername mypassword                                                                           
bash: ./port_forward.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory  
[root@transmission_1 /usr/local/etc/openvpn]#
```

I'm really not of a programer guy, but I manage to do a few things in the console. However, I don't know what to do with these errors.

First, should I login using tcsh or bash? Depending of how I login, I get different errors. If in tcsh, how to get pass the "Missing name for redirect error"?

Thanks!